# List view of certain files on sd card for Android

Tags: android

I am trying to create a mp3 player as an android app and I want to have it that it will automatically find any .mp3 file in my My Files folder. I don't want to have a direct path to a Music folder as I will include a link to Dropbox, where I can download a .mp3 file that is already on it. This will go to a Download folder and I want my MP3 player to pick it up for me.

How could I do this? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you simplify the question? exactly what are you trying to do?

Comment: In my sd card, I have a lot of audio files in different folders and sub folders. I am currently making an app that plays mp3 files only and I am looking to find out is there a method that I can automatically gather all of the mp3 files and show them in a List View.
I am only new to Android and don't understand how to read the Android website fully. I would be more seeking simple examples if possible?

Comment: What have you tried? What have you read already? What kind of help are you searching for?

Answer (score -1):

This method should work

```
private void searchMusic() {

    int count = 0;
    ArrayList<String> musicFiles;
    LinkedList<File> stack = new LinkedList<File>();
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());
    stack.add(directory);
    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
        File fmusic = stack.removeLast();
        File[] files = null;
        try {
            files = fmusic.listFiles();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        musicFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (files != null) {
            for (File folder : files) {

                if (folder.getName().endsWith(".mp3")
                        || folder.getName().endsWith(".ogg")
                        || folder.getName().endsWith(".wav")
                        && folder.isFile() && folder.canRead()
                        && !folder.getName().startsWith("._")) {

                    count++;
                    musicFiles.add(folder.getPath());
                }

                try {
                    if (folder.isDirectory()
                            && !FileUtils.isSymlink(folder)) {
                        stack.addFirst(folder);

                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
    return;

}
```

Comment: Imagine this code running on a 64 Gb storage, full of files of different types. This solution completely ignores the fact that Android has a concept called MediaStore, and a simple query can return you all music files that exist on the storage.

Comment: Oops...I missed that... Thanks @Egor.

Comment: Thanks for that Egor. I had a direct path set up, but I was told to change it so it could read files from every folder and sub folder and I have been stuck ever since

Comment: I have typed it in and I am getting one error and that is on FileUtils in the if statement. I do not know what it is and android is not giving me an option to import it. Would you mind explaining it to me and how I could fix the error. The error says "FileUtils cannot be resolved"

Comment: `FileUtils` is from "commons-io-2.1" jar library. For now you can comment it out and see if it works. Later on you can download the jar and it to the build path

Comment: yea I have tried commenting it out but it doesn't work. Ill have a look for a download of the jar file

Comment: Why dont you just remove that from the `if condition` ? That should work

Comment: I have downloaded the .jar file and now the error is fixed.
My next problem is getting it to show as a ListView on my phone. Right above the code given I have the onCreate class where it is like;
@Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  searchMusic();
 }
Needless to say I thought this would work but it is giving me a RunTimeException for my layout. But I have checked that and the layout is designed to be in the form of a ListView.
Any advice?

Comment: apologies for the untidyness of that last comment, as you might have gathered I am quiet new to Stack Overflow and still learning my way with it